# SimpleXML: Element 'id' is already used

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing, simple-framework

I'm sick and tired trying to parse one XML file. It's not mine, so I can't edit it.
Look at it first (I've cut unnecessary parts)

```
01  <feed>
02    <id>urn:ya.ru:feed/friends/12345678</id>
03    <author>
04      <name>Master</name>
05      <uri>http://test.ya.ru</uri>
06      <y:id>urn:ya.ru:person/12345678</y:id>
07    </author>
08    <title>List of friends posts</title>
09    <updated>2013-08-02T19:14:00Z</updated>
10    <entry>
11      <id>urn:ya.ru:post/110554367/3744</id>
12      <author>
13        <name>MrBigJoker</name>
14        <y:id>urn:ya.ru:person/110554367</y:id>     
15      </author>
16    </entry>
17  </feed>
```

You can see **ID** tags in lines 02, 06, 11 and 14. The problem is that I'm receiving an error "Element **ID** is already used" in line 14.
I'm using SimpleXML with the following three classes:

```
@Root (name = "feed")
public class Feed { // All lines

    @Element
    private String id;

    @Element
    private Author_feed author;

    @Element
    private String title;

    @Element
    private String updated;

    @ElementList(inline = true, type = String.class, entry = "entry")
    private List<Entry> entries;
```

---

```
@Root (name = "author")
public class Author_feed {  // Lines 03-07

    @Element
    private String name;

    @Element
    private String uri;

    @Element
    @Namespace(prefix = "y")
    private String id;
```

---

```
@Root (name = "entry/author")
class Author_entry {  // Lines 12-15

    @Element
    private String name;

    @Element
    @Path("author")
    @Namespace(prefix = "y")
    private String id;
```

---

```
@Root (name = "entry")
public class WhatsNewFeed_entry { // Lines 10-16

    @Element (name = "id")
    private String id_entry;

    @Element
    private Author_entry author;
```

Comment: what is Entry ? You didn't post the Entry class definition, shouldnt be WhatsNewFeed_entry?

Comment: Which exactly "Entry" are you talking about? Which line?

Comment: private List<Entry> entries;

Comment: This is list for <entry>...</entry> multiple elements

Comment: yeah i know... but how are you saying that List<Entry> is a List of WhatsNewFeed_entry ? That's what tou want isn't?, also why @Root (name = "entry/author"), just author

Comment: think should be   `@ElementList(inline = true, type = WhatsNewFeed_entry.class, entry = "entry")
    private List<WhatsNewFeed_entry> entries;`

Comment: Well, seems that problem is solved...but can you explain what was my mistake?

Comment: is my answer enough clear or you still have doubts? Glad to help you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Almost everything is good, I see two little mistakes.

First:

You don't need `@Root (name = "entry/author")`  just `@Root (name = "author")`

You should not depend of the parent of where it is going to be placed your class.

---

Second One

```
 @ElementList(inline = true, type = String.class, entry = "entry")
    private List<Entry> entries;
```

Should Be

```
 @ElementList(inline = true, type = WhatsNewFeed_entry.class, entry = "entry")
        private List<WhatsNewFeed_entry > entries;
```

In fact I think you just need

```
@ElementList(inline = true, entry = "entry")
            private List<WhatsNewFeed_entry > entries;
```

because you are already specifying the collection name in `List<WhatsNewFeed_entry >`

The mistake is that you aren't specifying what class to Use, you was Specifying it as a String, that's why I asked what was "Entry" you wasn't telling the Serializer to use the

```
WhatsNewFeed_entry
```

After that, it should work for you

---

As an additional oppinion, I don't really like the `@Root` because you are forcing the class to have an specific node name neither to force the properties or fields to be named as the XML expected tags , I think is a better approach to name it in the element, its more clear, you feel that you are making a real XML. And you design your classes as you

I'm not very good with java, come from C# world but it's so similar.

I would rewrite it a little like this:

```
  //First level
            @Root (name = "feed")
            public class Feed { // All lines

                @Element("id")
                private String id;

                @Element("author")
                private Author_feed author;

                @Element("title")
                private String title;

                @Element("updated")
                private String updated;

                @ElementList(inline = true, entry = "entry")
                private List<WhatsNewFeed_entry> entries;
            }

           //Note that there is no root because it was already defined in the first level,
//this way you can use the same class in differents node with different tag names, you 
//could even make an abstract class of author and in one just post the uri class isntead of
// 2 author classes with the same properties
        public class Author_feed {  // Lines 03-07

            @Element("name")
            private String name;

            @Element("uri")
            private String uri;

            @Element("id")
            @Namespace(prefix = "y")
            private String id;
        }


        class Author_entry {  // Lines 12-15

            @Element("name")
            private String name;

            @Element("id")
            @Namespace(prefix = "y")
            private String id;
        }


        public class WhatsNewFeed_entry { // Lines 10-16

            @Element (name = "id")
            private String id_entry;

            @Element("author")
            private Author_entry author;
        }
```

Hope it helps you to understand what was missing

Comment: That's very nice, thank you! Just one more question: how to fix the following error with "<y:agent/>" (not in this snippet) : Empty value for @org.simpleframework.xml.Element(data=false, name=, required=true, type=void) on field 'agent'

Comment: As I said im not very good with java but I searched and I look at you mistake , that its because you are getting an empty agent, am i right? If that, you should place in @Element(name="agent", required=false), hope it helps